# how to check if multiple array elements match given values from same method, in java

Tags: java, arrays, equals

if I have an array that stores a persons name address phone etc. and then I wanted search to see if a person exists, I would check if the array values equal given values, however, I'm not sure how to check for multiple array values in this statement

```
if (((Person) object.getFullName().equals(this.information[0] .....)))
```

How would I make sure this.information[1] is equal also being both [1] and [2] hold the persons full name?

I have included code below, the problem is in the last couple lines of the code.

Thanks for any help!!!!

```
public class Person
{
    private String [] information = new String [7];

    public Person()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < information.length; i++)
        {
            information [i] = null; 
        }
    }

    //construct a person object storing values in array
    public Person (String lName, String fName, String st, String city, String state, String zip, String phone)
    {
        information [0] = lName;
        information [1] = fName; 
        information [2] = st;
        information [3] = city;
        information [4] = state; 
        information [5] = zip;
        information [6] = phone; 

    }

    public void setFullName(String lastname, String firstname) 
    {
        if (lastname != null && firstname != null)
        {
            this.information[0] = lastname;
            this.information[1] = firstname;
        }
    }



    //set entire address together 
    public void setCompleteAddress(String street, String city, String state, String zip)
    {
        if (street != null && city != null && state != null && zip != null)
        {
            this.information[2] = street;
            this.information[3] = city;
            this.information[4] = state; 
            this.information[5] = zip;
        }
    }

    //set phone number 
        public void setPhoneNumber(String phone)
        {
            if (phone != null)
            {
                this.information[6] = phone;
            }
        }

        //get lastname 
        public String 


        //get full name 
        public String getFullname()
        {
            return this.information[0] + "  " + this.information[1];
        }

        //get full address
        public String getFullAddress()
        {
            return this.information[2] + " " +  this.information[3] + " "  + this.information[4] + " " + this.information[5];
        }


        //to string method 
        public String toString()
        {
            String temp = "Person: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < information.length; i++)
            {
                temp = temp + information[i];
            }
            return temp;
        }

        //searches if person exists 
        public boolean equals (Object object)
        {
            if (!(object instanceof Person || object == null)){
                return false 
            }
            if (((Person) object.getFullName().equals(this.information[0] .....)))
        }
}
```

Comment: You are totally losing the main benefits of OOP by putting you're class attributes in an array. I highly recommend you change that, before proceeding any further.

Comment: @ perception -- so you think I should just store all the values in different variables

Comment: Yes, definitely break out that array of values into different, specific variables.

Comment: @ perception I appreciate your recommendations, I changed it and works much better!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `toString()` method of `Person` to check equality in following way:

```
public boolean equals (Object object)
    {
        if (!(object instanceof Person || object == null)){
            return false 
        }
        Person per = (Person)object;
        if ((this.toString()).equals(per.toString()))
        {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner approach would be

- A Person Javabean with getters and setters for the various fields
- An equals method that compares these fields.

Comment: @ javapirate, yes, this is how I wanted to do this, I'm however, VERY new to programming and am still just learning the basics and have been bogging my brain for weeks and am getting myself a little mixed up. Thanks